# Pass Url to UIButton from Parse.com Data Browser

Tags: browser, uibutton, parse-platform

Im using Parse.com to populate information in my app, and have a column set up for URLs called 'url' and this contains a simple url such as "http://www.google.com.

I pull in all my data on a table view and then when navigating to my detail view have a UI Button that i wish to pass the url value from parse.com into. So that when this is clicked, 
the safari window on iphone launches and displays this site.

It the moment whatever i try does not work, ive tested displaying this value in a label to ensure im getting the right value from parse which i am. But this isnt passing to a UIButton.

the URL value is pulled in on the tableViewController with the below and pass through a segue,

```
listing.url = [object objectForKey:@"url"];
```

and then ive wired up a UIButton with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.co.uk"]];
```

which works with the hardcoded url, but i need to replace this URL with the correct URL from my parse.com data browser,

any help would be amazing,

thank you for taking the time in advance,

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are passing this data to a UIButton?

Comment: im trying to send the url value to the button so that when you click on this button it opens the url. depend on what cell is select in the table view leading to the detail view will determine what value is pulled from parse.com, but i need to know how to pass that value to the button so that url is launched.

Answer (score 0):

If `listing` is the `[segue destinationViewController]` from inside your `prepareForSegue` method, then `listing.url` will be storing the required URL inside your Detail View Controller.

So all you'd need to do from your Detail View Controller is:

```
- (IBAction)actionOpenWebpageOnSafari:(id)sender {  
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: self.url]];    
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil,Thanks for your feedback here. I tried this and the UIButton now doesnt launch the URL, any ideas? Is this something i can send to you?